# Font issue on AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm testing AMP on a website and that work well
But when i use the amp tool for validation

(https://search.google.com/search-console/amp)

and check the preview, the server respond 404 on my fonts files

I really don't understand why

The link from the preview :

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.permanence-telephonique-switchy.fr/amp

Comment: It's not reporting any 404 in *my console*, try disabling any extensions, clearing your cache or just used another browser to check if it works

Answer (score 0):

Only this one font fails: https://www.permanence-telephonique-switchy.fr/wp-content/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/templates/design-manager/design-3/fonts/icomoon.ttf?b9qrme

This is because it is served without a Content-Type header. All your other fonts are fine.